# Debounce strategy for Infinite Scroll in react-virtualized

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

I am trying to handle the scenario of my users trying to scroll faster or drag the scroll bar to do random seeks to parts of the list.

I have a dataset of ~20000 items that I am exposing to the user via Infinite scroll.

- I use a sparse array that gets hydrated based on the data fetches initiated via `loadMoreRows` which is the source of data to my list.
- I reserve spots with loadingIndicators in the sparse array when a request is in progress and use that to return true for `isRowLoaded={this.onIsRowLoadedCheck}` when a request is in progress.
- I use a `minimumBatchSize` of `100` and `threshold` of `50`

  ```
  <InfiniteLoader
      isRowLoaded={this.onIsRowLoadedCheck}
      loadMoreRows={this.onLoadMoreRows}
      rowCount={this.props.items.total}
      minimumBatchSize={100}
      threshold={50}
  >
      {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
          <AutoSizer disableWidth>
              {({ height }) => (
                  <List
                      ref={listViewRef => {
                          this.listView = listViewRef;
                          return registerChild(listViewRef);
                      }}
                      height={height}
                      onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                      rowCount={this.props.items.total}
                      noRowsRenderer={this.onNoRowsRenderer}
                      overscanRowCount={20}
                      deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
                      rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
                      rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
                      width={256}
                  />
              )}
          </AutoSizer>
      )}
  </InfiniteLoader>
  ```

I want to be able to debounce the calls the server so that I can avoid overloading the server until the user have stopped playing with the scroll bar.

```
    onLoadMoreRows = (loadMoreRowsRange: LoadMoreRowsRange) => {
        const { startIndex, stopIndex } = loadMoreRowsRange;
        this.props.fetchItems(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex + 1);
    };
```

Is there a strategy that is commonly used to handle this scenario?

I see a similar problem was discussed earlier in https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/202

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kind of late, but in case someone else needs it. You can just use a regular debounce strategy, something like (change 300 to whatever ms value you would like):

```
onLoadMoreRows = (loadMoreRowsRange: LoadMoreRowsRange) => {
  clearTimeout(this.loadRowsTimeout)
  this.loadRowsTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    const { startIndex, stopIndex } = loadMoreRowsRange;
    this.props.fetchItems(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex + 1);
  }, 300)
};
```

Or you can use a debounce function from a library, like lodash:

```
const debouncedLoadMore = _.debounce(onLoadMoreRows, 300)
```